# Spring Security UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken throws Exception before invoking super class method

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Why would one calls the super class method after an exception occurs? And if the exception occurs, the call stack would returns to the caller instead of executing the super class method?

```
public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (isAuthenticated) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Cannot set this token to trusted - use constructor which takes a GrantedAuthority list instead");
        }

        super.setAuthenticated(false);
    }
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) method in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken class is overridden method of AbstractAuthenticationToken class.

The only way to set the private authenticated property in this class is through its super.setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) method.

This overridden behavior of setAuthenticated method ensures that it can only be set true through one of its constructor:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(authorities);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        super.setAuthenticated(true); // must use super, as we override
}
```

And it doesn't allow to set authenticated property as true explicitly.

Regarding the calling of the super class method,there is a constructor which makes use of this function:

```
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Object principal, Object credentials) {
        super(null);
        this.principal = principal;
        this.credentials = credentials;
        setAuthenticated(false);
}
```

Comment: I understand the codes, but I want to find out why was the exception handled before the super method.

Comment: @ilovetolearn Because it allows you to set an authenticated token to 'false', trigger AuthenticationManager to run authenticate code again. Useful when you need temporaty authentication token mechanism.